# Ionic tab badges - How to count items in a different page list?

Tags: ionic-framework

**Tabs.html**

I have a two separate list under different tab pages (ex. Store list & Coupon list). I need my badge on the tabs to display the amount in each list instead of generic numbers as displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `badge` and `badge-style` attributes in the `<ion-tab>` directive. The only change you would need in your code is to expose the length of the list to the root of your app. This can be done using $rootScope or a parent controller with event broadcast

In your controller change count whenever length of list updates:

**Controller**

```
$rootScope.home = {
  itemCount: $scope.items.length
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Home" 
       badge="home.itemCount"
       badge-style="badge-balanced" 
       icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

A working sample is available in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNxNvm